# QGIS: centroid of polygon layer

Tags: qgis, centroids

I would like to determine the center of this layer, when I look for the centroid I get the centroid of each separate shape but I want the centroid of the total layer.

[image: grid]

Comment: Are you asking how to get the centroid of the bounding box?

Comment: You can dissolve features before processing: https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#qgisdissolve

Comment: @Erik yes, thank you for rephrasing!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Menu <kbd>Processing</kbd> > <kbd>Toolbox</kbd> > <kbd>[Geometry by expression](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#geometry-by-expression)</kbd> with this expression:

- for centroid of layer extent: `centroid (layer_property (@layer, 'extent'))`
- for collected polygons: `centroid (collect ($geometry))`

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve this using a virtual layer.

Go to the menu `Layer > Add Layer > Add/Edit Virtual Layer...`, enter the following query and adjust for your layer name. You can then export the layer to persist its content.

To use the layer extent:

```sql
select st_centroid(extent(geometry)) from myLayer
```

To use the union of the polygons:

```sql
select st_centroid(ST_Union(geometry)) from myLayer
```

[image]